# Trouble editing a link with str_replace

Tags: php

Ideally I want to use the php script as an include that will be on every page.

I have link: http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://123.456.789.101/~user/file.php

and I want to make it look like this: http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://MyUrl.com/file.php

Essentially I want to replace "123.456.789.101/~user" with "MyUrl.com"

There will be multiple links that I am going to need to change. Also, the file name "file.php" part changes for each page. I will not know what the exact page name will be.

I tried this but it does not work. If I echo the str_replace it gives me the correct link but I can not get the new link to replace the old link in the page.

```
<?php
$string = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://123.456.789.101/~user';
$pattern = '123.456.789.101/~user';
$replacement = 'MyUrl.com';
str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$string = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://123.456.789.101/~user';
$pattern = '123.456.789.101/~user';
$replacement = 'MyUrl.com';
$newString = str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
echo $newString;
?>
```

To replace in html use:

```
<a href="<?php echo $newString ?>>Anchor Text Here</a>
```

Comment: How would I get the newString to replace the old link?

Comment: Here is the full line of code that is in the site? 
<li class="message_sharing_facebook greyback_primary_accent"> <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://123.456.789.101/~user/file.php" target="_blank">F</a> </li>

Comment: Paul, thank you. I am using a CMS that seems to not like using an echo in a link. Do you know of any other methods?

Comment: What CMS? If you're editing the code (not trying to place the code in the WYSIWYG editor) it should work

Comment: I am using Pagelime. I was using a script to get the url and then echo the url into the link but the CMS seems to hard code the link in there when my client publishes the page. Which would be fine except that the CMS uses the IP address to access the site and so the link has the ip adderess in there and look dumb if you actually try to share the link in facebook.

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to help from here. I'm not familiar with Pagelime. Only thing I can recommend is trying to figure out how to edit the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the new string. `str_replace` returns the new string, it doesn't set it itself.

```
$string = str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

If you need to replace more than one IP you should look into using regular expressions.

Comment: Beaz, Sorry I am new to this. What do you mean "regular expressions?"
I will only have one IP I need to change. 
The difficulty I am having is getting the new string to replace the old one.
Thank you,

Comment: @BostonBB Have you tried inserting that code into your project? The variable `$string` will contain the replaced value. If you only need to match one IP address then using str_replace is fine.